# How do I make text on cursor show image with hover

Tags: html, css

I want )
If I put cursor on text , I want to show picture.
my code

```
<h1>hi</h1>
<img src=" ~~">

<style>
img { display : none; }
h1:hover { img { display : block; } }
</style>
```

but it doesnt work. what should i do?

Comment: your question is not understandable. Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same idea as this [w3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

**BUT NOTICE THAT** you must put the image inside a container so that when you hover the container element the image will be shown otherwise you have to use JavaScript like this:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const img = document.querySelector('img')
h1.addEventListener("mouseover", _ => {
    img.style.display = "block"
});
h1.addEventListener("mouseout", _ => {
    img.style.display = "none"
});
```